# CNTK python api - continue training a model

Tags: python, api, cntk

I have tried the [example](https://github.com/Microsoft/CNTK/blob/master/Tutorials/CNTK_203_Reinforcement_Learning_Basics.ipynb)

The example works fine.   I can restart the training, but am unable to continue the training after a model has been trained.  I have tried

```
agent.brain.model.load_model('setBdqn.mod', False)
```

but get an error message.

Comment: What is the error message?

Answer (score 1):

The error message says that the `load_model` function does not have 2 arguments. You need to change that to

```
agent.brain.model.load_model('setBdqn.mod')
```

I'm assuming that you changed the call to `save_model` to be `agent.brain.model.save_model('setBdqn.mod', False)` - the tutorial examples saves the model to a file named `dqn.mod`.